# OpenLayers 4 - Visiblity of a ol.layer.Image with maxResolutions equals to map resolution

Tags: openlayers

I have the next `ol.layer.Image`:

```js
let wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
    visible: true,
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS(/*params of the source*/),
    minResolution: 0.2578032858762812,
    maxResolution: 490.4640841686878
});
```

but when the map resolution is equal to layer maxResolution (490.4640841686878) the layer is not shown.

I can see on the [line 85 of layer.js](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/b456250cbea1648437dd2b2ed3975d3e5d76382f/src/ol/layer/layer.js#L85) that the layer is visible if the map resolution is **strictly** less than maxResolution:

```js
ol.layer.Layer.visibleAtResolution = function(layerState, resolution) {
    return layerState.visible && resolution >= layerState.minResolution &&
          resolution < layerState.maxResolution;
};
```

Is there any reason of this behaviour? Would it not be better if the map resolution is less **or equal** than maxResolution?